# MySQL table lock, or other possible solutions?

Tags: php, mysql, myisam

I have a security problem. I think to lock a table would be a solution, only I don't know how to properly do it in MySQL, PHP, and don't have enough time to search Google and documentations anymore.

So, the **task**:
Make a database and write a php code to randomly get lottery-tickets.
I have a table, that contains only a few row. (id, name, quantity)

*So for example:*

1 - no win - 20000
2 - Hello Kitty bag - 200
3 - a very nice pen - 50
etc.

I wrote the php, so the logic's the following:
1) Get the amount of evey tickets from the database, and create a PHP array that contains the intervals, like:
no win: 20000,
Hello Kitty bag: 20200,
a very nice pen: 20250.
2)Generate a random number from 1 to max, so I know what ticket the user got.
3)Update the database: subtract 1 from the proper row.

Now, this works great, **however the problem**:
What if I have a very large amount of users, and two or three of them clicks at the same time, random the same number, (lets assume it's hello kitty) but only have 1 of that item?
All the three of them subtract from the database, not stopping at 0. (In this example, we would have -2 hello kitty bag)

Huge issue, at least for me.
So in summary, my **question** is:
1)How can I lock the table from the selection, until I am ready to subtract? Is it a good solution?
2)Can I make it one query, or MySQL can't handle that?
3)Other solutions?

I appreciate every single answer, really!
Thanks in advance, also sorry for the long post, but wanted to keep things straight.

**[ SOLVED ]**
I used a stored procedure, here are the details.
I had some luck to have my server version above 5.x, since as I read the MyISAM system supports stored procedures only above this version.
I will write some code here hoping someone'll find it useful in the future:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE `name`(IN a_parameter INT(20))
  DECLARE some_text VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
  #now using all this stuff
  SELECT `name` INTO some_text FROM `users_table` WHERE `table_id` = a_parameter;
  SELECT some_text
END//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a transaction (documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)), and a table lock (read about the interaction between table lock and transactions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)).

To do it in one query you can build a stored procedure (documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)). I will go with a procedure.

If you are using PHP PDO you can read all about in in the manual ([here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), most important PDO:: beginTransaction and PDO:: commit). If you are still using `mysql` extendion you need to do it explicit like this:

```
mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');
// Because you cannot nest lock's and transactions, this is a workaround to lock the table
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM foo FOR UPDATE'); // Lock issued, the important part is "FOR UPDATE"
//[ your query's here ]

// if something goes wront, revert the changes
mysql_query('ROLLBACK');
// at the end commit the changes
mysql_query('COMMIT');
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, read it right away and solved the problem in ~2 hours of work I guess.
Sorry for the late response, intended to do it much earlier. :)
Did it with stored procedure, details coming in the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Lookup "transactions".. Use mysqli/pdo and their transaction capabilities

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/01/using-mysql-transactions-with-php/

http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-mysql/php-mysql-and-transaction-begin-commit-rollback/

etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look into these too as soon I have some spare time to do so. ^^